# Syncfusion WPF ReportWriter - How to set ReportParameters

Tags: reporting-services, report, rdlc, rdl, syncfusion

I'm migrating a few reports from SSRS to Syncfusions's Reports.  However, what I cannot seem to get to work is passing in parameters to the WPF ReportWriter.

I'm using this code:

```
ReportWriter reportWriter = new ReportWriter(reportPath);

List<ReportParameter> parms = new List<ReportParameter>();
parms.Add(new ReportParameter() { Name = "OrderId", Values = { "23456" }, Labels = { "test" } });

reportWriter.SetParameters(parms);
reportWriter.Save(@"c:\rdl\paul.pdf", WriterFormat.PDF);
```

It completely ignores the parameter, and does its own thing.  None of the samples show this, and the documentation is basically non-existent.  Perhaps someone else has experience of this?

Thanks,

Paul

Comment: This issue was not reproduced syncfusion latest release version . http://www.syncfusion.com/support/forums/winrtstudio/107138/Essential-Studio-2013-Volume-1-Final-Release-v111021-available-for-download

Answer (score 1):

This issue was resolved in syncfusion latest release version .

Thanks ,

Ragavan